# AngularJS adal Authentication to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azureportal

I have an angularJS project. I've included azure-blob-storage.js in my scripts and I am able to get access using SAS but not the AD authentication.

I have added Azure Storage API permissions to the AD App Registration and given the App Reader and Contributor roles to the storage account.

```
adalAuthenticationService.acquireToken({clientId},
        function(error, token) {
          // Handle ADAL Error
          if (error || !token) {
            return;
          }
        }).then(function (token) {
var tokenCredential = new AzureStorage.Blob.TokenCredential(token);
var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithTokenCredential({myStorageAccountURI}, tokenCredential);
```

I get the following error:

```
<Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature....</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Audience validation failed. Audience did not match.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

Comment: The error sounds like a problem with the configuration. Are you using this as the resource `"https://storage.azure.com/"`?

Comment: @juunas I am using  `"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net"`

Comment: Yeah, the error `Audience validation failed. Audience did not match.` means the token audience (= intended receiver) is wrong. You are most likely acquiring a token for your app with your client id. You need to switch it to the URI I mentioned in the call to acquireToken().

Comment: thank you, this worked in combination with setting explicit Blob Storage Reader and Contributor roles for my individual user account(not the app) If you answer question (not comment) i will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Audience validation failed. Audience did not match.` means the token audience (= intended receiver) is wrong. You are most likely acquiring a token for your app with your client id. You need to switch it to `https://storage.azure.com/` in the call to acquireToken().

And also your user needs to have the read/write access to the blobs as you found out :)